# Make ff-find-other-file ignore include directive in C

Tags: c, c-mode, ffap

I have a binding setup as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3510264/2228338), the problem is every time the cursor is on `#include "file"` it always tries to jump on this include. I want that no matter where there cursor is I get switched between header and the source files.

Comment: tried to achieve the same by setting (setq ff-ignore-include t) but does not seem to work for me either

Comment: I use `projectile-find-other-file`, works fine.